# How to create unique page for each row in php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have one table with 4 columns (id, name, surname, url). I want to create unique subpage for each row. (example.com/id?=444). So if I visit example.com?id=444 I will see data from row which has id 444.

Right now I have form where you add data into database:

```
 <form action="motogp.php" method="POST"> <input type="text"
 name="name" placeholder="Ime"> <input type="text" name="surname"
 placeholder="Priimek"> <input type="text" name="url" placeholder="URL
 do slike"> <button type="reset" class="ui button">Počisti</button>
 <button type="submit" class="ui positive button">Pošlji</button>
 </form>
```

motogp.php page code:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO person (name, surname, url)
VALUES
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[sruname]','$_POST[url]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }


$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM person ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<h2>VIDEO: " . $row['name'] . . $row['surname'] . " z drugo zaporedno zmago zmanjšal zaostanek za Marquezom</h2>";
  echo "<img src='images/avoter.png'>";
  echo "<img src='" .  $row['url'] ."'>";

}
```

Now it gives me just example.com/motogp.php not example.com/?id=444.

Comment: `example.com/?id=444` is shorthand for `example.com/index.php?id=444` (or whatever your default DirectoryIndex page is, index.html, etc).  Have you created that page?

Comment: I want that ?id=444 in motogp.php, when trying to access to /motogp.php?id=3 it gives me errors.

Comment: Then you'll want to change your links to include `motogp.php`.  And then you'll have a lot more issues, since that page looks like your "form handler".  The page you use to handle form data (the page referenced by your form's `action` should typically be different than the page you use to view data from the database.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use $_GET[''] rather than $_POST[''].

GET sends through all of your data through the URL in a format that is donated by

```
website.com/page.php?v=d&v=d
```

where v is a variable and d is some sort of data assigned to it.
If you want dynamically created pages. You need to send it through GET

So if the page you want is 
    website.com/page.php?id=4
in order to grab the data from the database entry with id 4 you need to do something like so

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id']; //in the case of the URL above, it will equal four
?>
```

Then you take that $id variable and run it through query grabbing the specific data you need.

If you want to make a form that sends the data over GET rather than POST, you just need to change the part where it says
    method="post"
to
    method="get"

I hope this helped!

EDIT:

Say you had a few links:

```
website.com/page.php?id=1
website.com/page.php?id=2
website.com/page.php?id=3
```

on page.php's code you can see what 'id' is equal to by using the code:

```
$var = $_GET['id'];
```

that will get the value of id out of the url.

```
So for website.com/page.php?id=1 $var is equal to 1,
for website.com/page.php?id=2 $var is equal to 2,
for website.com/page.php?id=3 $var is equal to 3,
```

Comment: So I place $id = $_GET['id']; in my motogp.php file? I really don't understand this..

Comment: You place $id= $_GET['id']; on the file which you're trying to make dynamic.

Comment: I placed it in motogp.php and if if type /motogp.php?id=1 it gives me error (Undefined index)